# How do I process part of image in Tesseract OCR 4? SetRectangle doesn't work

Tags: c++, tesseract, bounding-box

I'm having problems with Tesseract 4.1.1 when it comes to processing this image:

[image: The Adventure of the Beryl Coronet, page 7]

Tesseract 4.1 processes the entire image without problem when using the tessdata, tessdata_best, and tessdata_fast profiles.  But I want to process everything except the header and footer.  So I'm calling SetRectangle to tell Tesseract to just process a part of the image like this:

```
    __int32 lRectLeft = 0;
    __int32 lRectTop = 74; /* The height of the header is 74 pixels. */
    __int32 lRectWidth = 1737; /* The width of the image is 1737 pixels. */
    __int32 lRectHeight = 2250 - 74 - 74; /* Height of image = 2250. Height of footer = 74. */

    m_pTess->SetInputName(m_path.string().c_str());
    m_pTess->SetImage(m_pPix);
    m_pTess->SetRectangle(lRectLeft, lRectTop, lRectWidth, lRectHeight);
    m_pTess->Recognize(&monitor);
```

This worked in Tesseract 3, and it works in Tesseract 4 with the tessdata profile: the body of the page is recognized correctly.  For tessdata_best profile, the text comes out as

> TE Pr a oer tem Se orm frm ro fiom Trt T smirk afar fo le eno Cg Er nS Yen no ST TTT Er —_—— poe

I've tried rotating the image 180° and back before passing to Tesseract and I get different output:

> rn a Se LC A Gr eat LE ec 1 aan (1 aad TAT ene 1 ST PI EUR Fc I EL Sn Na SR I At Arex aC 1a (11 1G 15 ATT

I've tried adjusting the top and bottom margins in the bounding rectangle and the output changes to different garbage:

> "Tt is absolutely essential to me." said he. "that T should ha
>
> i rT LUT reid ered to
> eC
> Er
> Ye ao SL
> SE
> "Bor how lone. mav T ask. do vou want this
>
> "Next Mondav T have a large sum due to me. and I sha
>
> DO
> pga
> ST
> "should be hapnv to advance it without

Is it SetRectangle or is it some other method that I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this: create a new, blank pix in Leptonica and copy over just the chunk of image that I need to have recognized.

```
    PIX* pNewImage = pixCreateTemplateNoInit(m_pPix);
    pixSetBlackOrWhite(pNewImage, L_SET_WHITE);

    pixRasterop(pNewImage, lRectLeft, lRectTop,
        lRectWidth, lRectHeight,
        PIX_SRC, m_pPix, lRectLeft, lRectTop);
```